# SQL: retrieve the most recent order for each client

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables with a one-to-many relationship (e.g. clients table and orders table; every client may have placed multiple orders). For each client, I need to retrieve one order only, as defined by a specific criterion (e.g. the most recent order).

I need to do this in both PostgreSQL 9.1 and Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (different data in the two systems, but very same issue). The tables are about 2.5 million records (clients) and 10 million records (orders).

I was thinking of using outer apply in SQL server and rank over partition or lateral joins in PostgreSQL but am not too sure about the syntax.

A simple `max(order_date)` ... `group by clientid` wouldn't be enough, because I need all the fields from the order table. For example, I need an output like

```
c.clientid, c.client_name, o.order_id, o.order_date, o.order_amount, o.product_ordered
where c = the clients table and o = the orders table.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see how a lateral join would be necessary. This is a good old "greatest-n-per-group" problem which can be solved with a plain join and a window function:

```
select *
from clients c
  join (
     select clientid, order_id, order_date, order_amount, product_ordered 
            row_number() over (partition by client_id order by order_date desc) as rn
     from orders
  ) o on o.clientid = c.clientid and o.rn = 1;
```

For Postgres this could be made more efficient by using `distinct on` instead of the window function. If you have an index on `client_id, order_date` this should perform fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you could do this. Written / tested for SQL 2005. Not too sure of it's performance with your high quantity of records.

```
SELECT 
    c.clientid, 
    c.client_name, 
    o.order_id, 
    o.order_date, 
    o.order_amount, 
    o.product_ordered
FROM c JOIN o ON c.clientid = o.clientid
WHERE order_id IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 order_id
    FROM o AS o2
    WHERE o.clientid = o2.clientid
    ORDER BY order_date DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server I would use `OUTER APPLY`.

```
SELECT
    clients.clientid
    ,clients.client_name
    ,LastOrder.order_id
    ,LastOrder.order_date
    ,LastOrder.order_amount
    ,LastOrder.product_ordered
FROM
    clients
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            orders.order_id
            ,orders.order_date
            ,orders.order_amount
            ,orders.product_ordered
        FROM orders
        WHERE orders.clientid = clients.clientid
        ORDER BY order_date DESC
    ) AS LastOrder
;
```

If you have an index on (orders.clientid, orders.order_date) and add other columns to the index as included, then `OUTER APPLY` should be a seek on that index.
So, there should be a single seek on orders index for each row in clients table.
If the index doesn't include all other columns, there would be a seek and lookup.

If you don't want to get clients that don't have any orders at all use `CROSS APPLY` instead of `OUTER APPLY`.

I think this kind of `OUTER APPLY` would be more efficient than generating ROW_NUMBERS() for all orders and then discarding most of the results and using only the first rows.

Of course, you should measure actual performance of different variants with your system.

Unfortunately, I don't know Postgres.

Comment: With Postgres you can do the same using `join lateral` (which is the ANSI standard for what Microsoft called `apply`) would indeed be interesting if that performs better.

Comment: @Pythonista anonymous, how did you eventually solve the problem? Was any of the provided suggestions useful for you? If yes, please upvote them and accept an answer that was most useful.